# Tons of spam on dreamhost mail user account

Tags: email, spam, web-hosting

I use dreamhost for my webserver/ email host.

I have about 25 users on one domain. and 1 of these users is absolutely inundated with spam every day.

I have tried using dreamhosts poor blacklist feature, which was semi working (still letting a lot through) but I reached the 1000 email blacklist maximum very quickly.

I have the ability to switch to google apps but that would be very expensive for 25 users.

What options do I have aside from changing hosts with better spam filtering?

I don't think its possible to only switch 1 user to google apps, it has to be the whole domain.

There are other benefits to switching but I don't think they outweigh the cost for this company.

Answer (score 5):

According to [DreamHost](http://dreamhost.com/servers/vps/), your VPS comes with full root access. That means you can set up your own mail transfer agent (MTA), instead of using their preconfigured one.

For example, you could use the MTA Postfix and one or two good real-time blacklists (e.g., Spamhaus and UCEPROTECT). THis is what I do, and the results are much better than any preconfigured solution I have tried.

Tutorial: [Postfix - Debian Wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/Postfix) (covers setup and RBL)

Answer (score 1):

> What options do I have aside from changing hosts with better spam
>   filtering?

You don't have a great deal of options since you are using a budget hosting.  There is this old age saying that "You get what you pay for" there is a reason Dreamhost is inexpensive.  Since you have your own private server, you should have root access, this means you could use any number of solutions to handle spam.  Of course getting rid of the problem user is always an option.

Comment: Well I am paying for the private server. So it's not the "cheapest" by any means. but I do get your point..

Comment: @Sackling - This is important information to know.  If you are not on a virtual shared server, your root access, allows you to do a few things.